# how to apply masked input plug-in to a password field?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I am trying to apply masked input plugin ( jquery.maskedinput.min.js ) to a password field in order to create :

```
****-****-****
```

It is basically a registration key separated by dashes.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#registrationKey").mask("9999-9999-9999");

        $("#registrationKey").keyup(function(e) {
              self = $(this);
              rkValue = self.val().replace(/[^\d\-]/g, '');
              self.val(rkValue);
              console.log("value = " + rkValue);
              self.attr("regKey", rkValue);
        });
});

<input type="password" id="registrationKey" name="registrationKey" regKey="" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" >
```

I am having 2 problems. First one is that the field is already populated due to mask being applied. Second problem is it won't apply a dash after every 4th digit.

Is there a way to accomplish this via pure javascript or via this plug-in?

By the way, I have seen something similar in another post. However, it is very buggy if a user places the mouse in the middle of the field, or highlights some section of the text and deletes it.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Would be surprised to do that with a input type password. The brower is the boss always showing the dots there. If you really need this you use multiple input fields or a single text field where you can fake password characters.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing something similar for a project I'm working on. I used a standard text input with the mask specified as the default value, with some code for the events `keydown` and `paste`.
It doesn't work with pasted text, but it'll prevent users from altering the mask by pasting something into the field.

Here you can find a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/apy5am74/.